# AS3 asdoc inheritance issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, documentation-generation

I have an API that inherits flash.display.Sprite .When I try to generate the ASDocs for the API, The ASdoc shows that my class inherits from flash.display.Sprite, but doesnt link or there is no click-able link to the Sprite's ASDoc. Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

The command I am using in my ant script is

```
<java jar="${asdoc.jar}" dir="${FlexSDK.dir}/frameworks" fork="true" maxmemory="256m" failonerror="true">
   <arg line='-load-config "${flex-config.xml}"'/> 
   <arg line='-source-path ${src.dir}'/>
   <arg line='-doc-sources ${src.dir}/com'/>
   <arg line='-output ${docs.dir}'/>
   <arg value='-library-path+=${FlexSDK.dir}/frameworks'/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ASDoc generates documentation for your classes, not for the Flash's default classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the Flash and Flex docs as long as you have access to them locally to your build. By default they aren't included, but if you have access you just need to include another library path. See this post for more details:

http://unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/01/28/building-asdocs-with-ant/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I did try that too, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Short: 
Not possible because we don't have access to the commented source for flash.*.

Long:
AFAICT, ASDoc works from source, and source only. While the Flex framework classes are open source, the core Flash framework classes are not. They are delivered as a binary in the Flex SDK: [flex_sdk]/frameworks/libs/player/10.1/playerglobal.swc. You can unzip this, but it just contains the catalog.xml and binary library.swf.

Related query: 
http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/87106/

(Note to others looking to include the *Flex* SDK classes in their ASDocs: see [flex_sdk]/asdoc/build.xml to get a jump start configuring asdoc.)